# Retrieve records from mongodb by array of IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using node/mongodb/mongoose, how do I retrieve a set of records via an array list of their IDs.

Have had no luck with:

```
var ids = ['50829a8f558866ad21000921',
    '50829a8f558866ad21000920',
    '50829a8f558866ad2100091d',
    '50829a8f558866ad21000915',
    '50829a8f558866ad2100090b',
    '50829a8f558866ad21000906'];

Schema
    .find()
    .in("_id", ids)
    .run(callback);
```

Guessing Query.in() is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

```
Schema
    .find({"_id": {$in: ids}})
    .run(callback);
```